# Why does my animation in my cell disappear when the cell is selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have an animation as my image in one of my tableview's cells. When it is clicked, it turns the default blue and the image disappears!  The navigation loads the new view, and when it I go back to the first view, hoping my animation returns, alas, there is no image :(.  I don't do anything in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function besides play a beep sound and push the new view.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  // Set up the cell…
  switch (indexPath.section) {
   case 0:
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TBR2.png"]];
    cell.primaryLabel.text = @"Text 2";
    cell.primaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    //textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.secondaryLabel.text = @"Text 1";
    cell.secondaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    cell.myImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events2.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events3.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events4.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events5.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events6.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events7.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events8.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events9.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events10.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events11.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events12.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events13.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events14.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events16.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events17.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events18.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events19.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events20.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events21.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events22.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events23.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events24.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events25.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_events26.png"],nil];

    // all frames will execute in .5 seconds
    cell.myImageView.animationDuration = .5;
    // repeat the annimation forever
    cell.myImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    // start animating

    [cell.myImageView startAnimating];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    break;
   case 1:
    cell.primaryLabel.text = @"Label 1";
    cell.secondaryLabel.text = @"Search";
    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"magglass.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    break;
   default:
    break;
  }
  return cell;
 }

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ping" ofType:@"wav"];

 AVAudioPlayer *myAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]error:NULL];
 myAudio.delegate = self;
 [myAudio play];

 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

  Page2 *page2 = [[Page2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page2" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:page2 animated:YES];
  [page2 release];
}
```

Comment: Consider using <pre><code> for the code, it's pretty unreadable.

Comment: Aleph: I fixed it while fixing the tags.

Comment: Did you try "[tableView reloadData];" when you go back to the first view?

Comment: can you try whether you are able to set `animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;` while adding animation?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on iOS 8.4 and onwards and I've found a solution. Maybe it's not very good but it works.

I figured out that the problem is only with the animated image and only when the image changes its state to highlighted. So my workaround for `UIImageView` is as follows:

- Subclass `UIImageView`
- Override `setHighlighted` method to exclude highlighted state from animated image.

My `setHighlighted` method looks like:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {

    if (!self.isAnimating) {
        [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    }
}
```

Also, If you don't need visible selection on the cell you can set `selectionStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` of your table.